# Google Fonts violates Content Security Policy using ASP.NET

Tags: reactjs, .net, content-security-policy

I am trying to configure Content Security Policy in my .NET api project and when I run `dotnet watch` I get errors in the console.

I have .NET 7.0 ASP.NET Web API and React client.

I've read quite a few threads and questions about this but still can't seem to get any success.

Error message:

```
[Report Only] Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following  
Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com".  
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash  
('sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='), or a nonce  
('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I have moved all my inline styles into CSS files but still same errors appear.
When I search for style in VSCode there is no results for inline style code.

[image]

I had similar errors for cloudinary and accuweather but they disappeared immediately after I added them to the exceptions.

This is my code in start up class:

```
 app.UseCspReportOnly(opt => opt
.BlockAllMixedContent()
.StyleSources(s => s.Self().CustomSources(
    "https://fonts.googleapis.com"
    ))
.FontSources(s => s.Self().CustomSources(
    "https://fonts.gstatic.com",
    "https://maps.gstatic.com",
    "data:"
))
.FormActions(s => s.Self())
.FrameAncestors(s => s.Self())
.ImageSources(s => s.Self().CustomSources(
    "https://res.cloudinary.com",
    "https://developer.accuweather.com",
    "data:"
))
.ScriptSources(s => s.Self().CustomSources(
    "https://connect.facebook.net",
    "https://maps.googleapis.com"
    ))
);
```

This is my html file

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta name="description"
              content="Web site created using vite" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/logo.ico" />
        <title>Твоята риболовна изстория</title>
        <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-49eab6e8.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-959f16a9.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've tried modifying the manifest.json file or adding a meta tag to the html file as it was discribed in other answers but none of these help.

This is the response header:
[image]

When I click on the error I see "index-d1a82650.js:868" which is my production js file.

[image]

When I click on the link it goes to this code
[image]

```
 function Bde(e, t) {
        t === void 0 && (t = {});
        var n = t.insertAt;
        if (!(!e || typeof document > "u")) {
            var r = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
              , i = document.createElement("style");
            i.type = "text/css",
            n === "top" && r.firstChild ? r.insertBefore(i, r.firstChild) : r.appendChild(i),
            i.styleSheet ? i.styleSheet.cssText = e : i.appendChild(document.createTextNode(e))
       }
    }
```

Maybe I'm missing something. Looking for advice on what I'm missing and where to look for the problem. If additional information is needed, please write a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is a script that modifies the style of an element, this will be counted as an inline style. Check the code link in the error message to see which script it is. If it is your own script you should modify css classes, not styles directly. If this is a third party script with a static modification you can use the hash value.  If it is a third party with dynamic modification you will replace/rewrite/accept a weaker CSP.

Comment: I've updated my post with new images if this can help. Does that this is my js production file means that its my own script ?

Comment: This script seems to be inserting an inline script. If this is not a dynamic script you should move it to a file instead. If you need something to be dynamic your should work with adding/removing css classes instead.

Comment: how should I check if this script is dynamic as this code is not written by me. I think it is default react code.

Comment: You could try to add the hash value for the script and see if it changes. If you just have to keep adding hashes due to this one script, it is definitely dynamic...

Comment: It's definitely dynamic, because when I add a hash the errors go away but keep generating errors with a different hash values. What should I do in this case ?

Comment: The code is likely not accepting nonces, which means your options are pretty much to either rewrite the code to modify css classes instead of styles directly, or to accept using 'unsafe-inline'. Using 'unsafe-inline' for styles isn't all that bad if you lock down the rest of your policy, see https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/. Scanners and auditors don't understand this, so it might not be a good options after all.